# Remove a value from string in hidden field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden field that stores all of the id's of images that have been uploaded for a specific post.

The hidden field HTML looks something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_images" name="post_images" value="1,2,3,4,5" />
```

When an image is deleted from the post, I need to remove it's image_id from that hidden field. So if I delete image_id 4 from the post, the hidden field needs to update to be `value="1,2,3,5"`

I'm open to changing the way I store the image_id's for the post to a different format if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *could* use this dirty regex:

```
$("#post_images").val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace( new RegExp('(?=(?:^|,))(,?)' + id + '(?=(?:,|$)),?'), '$1' );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43hhs/

---

A more sane way would be to use array splicing:

```
$("#post_images").val(function(i, v) {
    var values = v.split(','),
        i = $.inArray(id.toString(), values);

    if ( i != -1 ) {
        values.splice(i, 1);
        return values.join(',');
    }
    else {
        return v;
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khHPq/

Comment: Your code doesn't work, in either case. See http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/27Ku6/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mUtRm/1/

Comment: @Blazemonger - Thanks for your input. I'd answered in haste, and missed a lot of cases. By bad, and I hope to learn from my mistake. I've updated my answer(s), but the regex turned out to be crazy complicated; I wouldn't use that in a million years. Just leaving it here to be improved upon. There should be a better way though...

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Mwsu/15/

```
$(".imageRemove").click( function()
{
    $(this).hide();

    var values = $("#post_images").val().split(",");
    var newValue = "";

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( $(this).attr("id") != values[i] )
        {
            newValue = newValue + values[i] + ",";
        }
    }

    $("#post_images").val( newValue );
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using jQuery's `data` method instead, which lets you store true arrays. If you need data to be passed in the `value` of the elements, you can convert back and forth at your convenience, such as in an `.on('submit', ...)` handler.

The following code is a bit cumbersome, but I think it communicates the idea.

```
$pi = $('#post_images');

$pi.data('values', $pi.val().split(',') );
// now .data('values') is a true JS array
console.log($pi.data('values').indexOf("3")); // 2

$pi.data('values').splice(2,1); // removes the third element
console.log($pi.data('values')); // ["1","2","4","5"]

$pi.val( $pi.data('values').join(',') );
console.log($pi.val()); // "1,2,4,5"​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vx3XL/2/

Answer (score 0):

using that, to me easiest way to go would be to have the value start and end in ',', then you can just do a

```
$("#post_images").val($("#post_images").val().replace("," + idtoremove + ",", ",")
```

Comment: What if the 'idtoremove' is the last on the list? Since it doesn't end with a comma, ("," + idtoremove + ",") won't exist in the value.

Comment: that's why I said 'start and end in ','.  I do this all the time, works perfectly and it's really fast

Answer (score 0):

```
var theVals = $(':input').val().split(','); //split the values into an array
var myVal = '4'; //this should be the ID of the element you want to remove
if($.inArray(myVal, theVals)){ //is the item in the array
  index = theVals.indexOf(myVal); //if it is, then get the index position
  theVals.splice(index, 1); //starting at the index of the element in the array, remove 1 element
  $(':input').val(theVals); //update the input with the new array of IDs
}
console.log($(':input').val()); //general purpose to visualize this output
```

[a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/84cGz/)